# Item vs BindItem: Data Binding in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, asp.net-4.5

ASP.NET 4.5 introduces [strongly typed data controls](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097385).

From what I could gather there are two options how to access the data item

```
<%# Item %>
```

and

```
<%# BindItem %>
```

I don't quite understand though, what exactly is the difference between those two? Is this just a matter of naming? Can they be used interchangeable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the case:

`Item`: for one-way binding expressions.

`BindItem`: for two-way data-binding expressions.

Comment: Could you elaborate what that is?

Comment: Sure, one-way is mostly for readonly data controls (like repeater / listview) and two-binding is for editing data controls (like formview).